# Allow Upgrade of Application

Tags: c#, wix, upgrade

I am trying to allow upgrade of my application.   If the user installs 1.0.0 then the next time I release a version I can give them 1.1.0 and they can install that.  `Overwriting | removing | replacing the first version`  There should only be installed **one** version in Control panel -> uninstall or change a program.

My problems are:

If I don't set product id equal * (use $(var.ProductId)"  instead) I get

> Another Version of this product is already installed. Installation of
>   this version can not continue ...

If I set it equal to * then it installs the new version and I have two versions installed.

I have created a simple wix application to test this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?define ProductVersion="!(bind.FileVersion.MyAssemblyDll)"?>
<?define UpgradeCode="f4d7f199-28f6-45d5-ad99-7c62938274be"?>
<?define ProductId="{6408D956-40DA-4AEE-883E-5425F1562004}"?>
<?define Version="1.2.0"?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="$(var.ProductId)" Name="UpgradeTest" Language="1033" Version="$(var.Version)" Manufacturer="xxx" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <!-- prevents down gradeing -->
    <!-- one upgrade installes new version first then removes the old one. -->
        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." Schedule="afterInstallExecute"/>
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="UpgradeTest" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="UpgradeTest" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
             <Component Id="ProductComponent">
         <File Id="Product.wxs" Source="Product.wxs" KeyPath="yes" />
             </Component> 
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I have been trying to get this to work for several days now I have exhausted all tutorials as far back to 2008.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

```
<MajorUpgrade AllowDowngrades="no" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed."   AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no" />
```

> Bad:  Results in two versions in control panel.

**Update two:**

```
<Upgrade Id ="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)">
   <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductFullVersion)" OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERVERSIONDETECTED"/>
   <UpgradeVersion Maximum="$(var.ProductFullVersion)" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED"/>
</Upgrade>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallValidate"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Condition Message="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed. If you are sure you want to downgrade, remove the existing installation via Programs and Features.">Not NEWERVERSIONDETECTED</Condition>
```

> Bad:  Results in two versions in control panel.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done it is using a GUID for the `UpgradeCode` but leaving the `Id` of the product at `*`.
Then set a reinstallation property to `amus` to reinstall your product the way you want.

It will kind of look like this

```
<Product Id="*"
       Name="YourProductName"
       Language="1033"
       Version="YourProductVersion"
       Manufacturer="YourCompany"
       UpgradeCode="{SOME-GUID}">

<SetProperty Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="amus" After="FindRelatedProducts">Installed AND REMOVE&lt;&gt;"ALL"</SetProperty>
```

For `amus` you can refer to the Microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx) but be careful, though. With the `a` value it will reinstall your application even if the installed one has a newer version. But you will figure out which characters you need for your installer.

Comment: Didn't work.  It did ask me to reboot the pc to finish the install which I haven't seen before.   But I still ended up with two versions installed on the machine instead of just the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `<MajorUpgrade>` element to this

```
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" Schedule="afterInstallExecute"/>
```

From the [Wix website](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html)

> When set to no (the default), installing a product with the same version and upgrade code (but different product code) is allowed and treated by MSI as two products. When set to yes, WiX sets the msidbUpgradeAttributesVersionMaxInclusive attribute, which tells MSI to treat a product with the same version as a major upgrade.

So it is treated as if your two installs are unrelated. I think this is weird behaviour but blame Microsoft for that.

Comment: Think you misunderstood the part where i only want one version of my application installed the newest.  This is installing two versions I now have 1.0.0.0 and 1.2.0.0 installed.  I only want one version of my application installed.